# How to filter a column and validate another column using that filtered data frame while using Foundry Data Expectations?

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

I'm using Data Expectations to validate whether a specific column is satisfying some required condition or not. I was able to write the code for checking whether a column is unique or not. But I'm not able to write the code when it comes to filtering a column and then for that resulting dataframe checking whether another column is unique or not.
For instance, please find the below 2 scenarios, in both the scenarios we need to check whether department_id = "CSE" is having unique roll_no :

1. Scenario 1:

| reg_no | department_id | roll_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CSE | 1 |
| 2 | ECE | 1 |
| 3 | ECE | 2 |
| 4 | CSE | 2 |
| 5 | ME | 1 |
| 6 | EEE | 1 |
| 7 | CSE | 2 |

In this case , It should fail since CSE is having duplicate roll_no :

2. Scenario 2:

| reg_no | department_id | roll_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CSE | 8 |
| 2 | ECE | 2 |
| 3 | ECE | 5 |
| 4 | CSE | 4 |
| 5 | ME | 3 |
| 6 | EEE | 2 |
| 7 | CSE | 1 |

In this case, the job should pass since deparment_id = "CSE" is having unique roll_no values.
Please let me know on how to satisfy the above 2 scenarios where the dataframe should be filtered first and then check whether a column is unique using foundry data expectations.

Comment: What is the output you are looking for? a dataframe with duplicated CSE records removed?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply build two dataframes and check if they have the same size:

- for the first one just filter `department_id='CSE'` and select `roll_no`
- for the second one filter `department_id='CSE'`, select `roll_no` and call `distinct()`

if they are the same size your dataframe was unique with respect to department_id

Answer (score 1):

IIUC - There is two way to answer this problem -

**A generic code that will tell only duplicate values -**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "CSE", 1),(2, "ECE", 1),(3, "ECE", 2),(4, "CSE", 2),(5, "ME", 1),(6, "EEE", 1),(7, "CSE", 2)],["reg_no","department_id","roll_no"])
df.show()
df \
    .groupby(['department_id', 'roll_no']) \
    .count() \
    .where('count > 1') \
    .sort('count', ascending=False) \
    .show()
```

**This will help you identify a depertment_id is unique or not**

```
_w  = W.partitionBy("department_id").orderBy("department_id")

df = df.withColumn("roll_no_list", F.collect_list("roll_no").over(_w)).withColumn("roll_no_set", F.collect_set("roll_no").over(_w))
df = df.withColumn("cond_col", F.when(F.size(F.col("roll_no_list")) == F.size(F.col("roll_no_set")), "Unique").otherwise("Not Unique"))
df.show()
+------+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+----------+
|reg_no|department_id|roll_no|roll_no_list|roll_no_set|  cond_col|
+------+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+----------+
|     1|          CSE|      1|   [1, 2, 2]|     [1, 2]|Not Unique|
|     4|          CSE|      2|   [1, 2, 2]|     [1, 2]|Not Unique|
|     7|          CSE|      2|   [1, 2, 2]|     [1, 2]|Not Unique|
|     2|          ECE|      1|      [1, 2]|     [1, 2]|    Unique|
|     3|          ECE|      2|      [1, 2]|     [1, 2]|    Unique|
|     6|          EEE|      1|         [1]|        [1]|    Unique|
|     5|           ME|      1|         [1]|        [1]|    Unique|
+------+-------------+-------+------------+-----------+----------+
```